# Terminator/config Is not in .config file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminator

## Description of Problem:

I'm trying to use terminator in a bash script but I keep getting an error stating that No such file or directory: `~/.config/terminator/config`. and its keeping the terminals from popping up on screen.  However when I run terminator on my terminal the window pops up. So I definitely have terminator installed I just don't know where terminator/config is.

## Questions and summary of issue:

1. How would I check if terminator/config exists on my system?
2. Where would I find it since it isn't in `~/.config`?
3. Why would this be happening?

## Solutions that I know don't work and extra information

1. Uninstalling and reinstalling. I did it before I came to this site to ask.
2. These are the commands I used to install it the first time:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-terminator
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install terminator

3. I don't think I was at the home directory when I installed terminator if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

> How would I check if terminator/config exists on my system?

Either find the file using 'locate':

```sh
$ sudo apt install locate -y
$ sudo updatedb # this is to update the file database
$ locate config
```

Or even better, use stat:

```sh
$ stat ~/.config/terminator/config
```

> Where would I find it since it isn't in ~/.config?

If the file does not exist, you cannot find it ofcourse.

Perhaps create the file yourself.

```sh
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/terminator/
$ touch ~/.config/terminator/config
```

> Why would this be happening?

The systems provides an error message. Because it expects there to be file, which isn't.
Please [read the documentation](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-terminator_config/).

Answer (score 2):

the config file is created automatically if you make some permanent changes.

- start terminator
- right click -> preferences
- go to tab profiles -> sub tab colors
- choose a different color profile e.g. "Solirized light"  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYFyp.png
- close preferences and confirm the color of the terminator has
  changed.

  now the file "~/.config/terminator/config" has been created, containing the current user configuration.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! :-)